# Spring 5 consume multiple MediaType

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE
I have an endpoint and would like to consume multiple MediaType.
In particular `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` type.
At the moment I have the below code. It works for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but doesn't work for `application/json`.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.POST,
                    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE},
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> validate(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyDetails details) {
        return something();
    }
```

I tried to put a content negotiator in my configuration, but still doesn't work.

```
    @Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.favorPathExtension(false)
                      .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .mediaType("x-www-form-urlencoded", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        }
```

How can I allow the endpoint to accept these 2 media types?

Answer (score 0):

exchange {} to [] for consumes
Try it:

```
consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE],
```

reference: [Spring RequestMapping - Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping)

Comment: this is not suppported